# Is there a way to show icons on a git repo folder like tortoiseGit?

Tags: git

Is there a way which could let me know all the file status by just looking at the folder view, like what TortoiseHg, TortoiseSVN, TortoiseGit did on windows?

Now my git repo folder looks the same as other folders. If I want to view file status I have to type `git status` in the command line. I want some icons which could inform me the file/folder status at my first glance on the folder view.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

**EDIT**

I googled it, and what I'm asking for is called the `overlay icon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RabbitVCS is a set of graphical tools written to provide simple and
>    straightforward access to the version control systems SVN (Subversion) and Git.

```
apt-cache search ^rabbitvcs
rabbitvcs-nautilus-3.0 - Nautilus 3.0 extension for RabbitVCS
rabbitvcs-cli - Command line interface for RabbitVCS
rabbitvcs-gedit - Gedit extension for RabbitVCS
rabbitvcs-nautilus - Nautilus 2 extension for RabbitVCS
rabbitvcs-thunar - Thunar extension for RabbitVCS
rabbitvcs-core - Easy version control
rabbitvcs-nautilus3 - Nautilus 3 extension for RabbitVCS
```